# How to use dbo procedure to execute for different schema?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a schema `[dbo]`, and in that schema, I have created a stored procedure `dbo.GetAccount`:

```
SELECT * FROM tblAccount
```

Then, I have created a schema `[ABC]` with user named `UserABC`.

Now, I would like to login with `UserABC` and execute `dbo.GetAccount` for schema `[ABC]` to get all user of it and don't want to change code of `dbo.GetAccount`. So, how can I do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct,

```
SELECT * FROM tblAccount actualy means SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tblAccount]
```

So your procedure will always execute the tblAccount from the dbo schema.

If you want ( let's say ) have a "general" procedure that can be execute from more schemas I say you try with dinamic sql.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAccout] 
        @schema 
 as   
       declare @sql varchar(200)
    set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ['+@schema+'].[tblAccount]'

    exec(@sql)
```

then you run `exec [dbo].[GetAccout] ABC`

This should select all info from YourSchema.tblAccount.

I can't test it right now, but I should work. Also remember the table must be in that schema!

But if you can't change all the the procedure I can't think of a solution.

Comment: You're right. But I want to keep the code of stored procedure dbo.GetAccout (I don't want to change it). Any way? Thank you very much

Comment: Don't use `['+@schema+']`, is a SQL injection opportunity. Use [`QUOTENAME(@schema, '[')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx).