# Alter Schema of all stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a bunch of stored procedures (more than 200) in my database.

I have to change the schema of those now. They have the schema `ABC`. I have to change it to `XYZ`.

I know that I can use this query

```
ALTER SCHEMA XYZ TRANSFER ABC.STOREDPROCEDURE
```

to achieve this.

But the number of stored procedures is huge. I cannot do it one by one. Is there any other way to do this task? Can I use while loop for it?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Sql Server to generate the code for me.

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA XYZ TRANSFER ABC.' + name
FROM sys.Procedures
```

Then copy and paste the results into a Sql Window and hit the Execute button...

Answer (score 2):

Run this script to generate the statements you need

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA NewSchemaName TRANSFER ' + SysSchemas.Name + '.' + DbObjects.Name + ';'
FROM sys.Objects DbObjects
INNER JOIN sys.Schemas SysSchemas ON DbObjects.schema_id = SysSchemas.schema_id
WHERE SysSchemas.Name = 'OldSchemaName'
AND (DbObjects.Type IN ('P'))
```

Comment: @Wofl No need for while,just right click-select all-copy-paste in a new query window.

Comment: I want to use while loop because my goal is to resolve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401919/how-to-use-dbo-procedure-to-execute-for-different-schema. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using following query:

```
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(Max)
SET @Command = (SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA XYZ TRANSFER ABC.' + name +'; '
                FROM sys.Procedures
                FOR XML PATH(''))


EXEC(@Command)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in powershell

```
import-module sqlps;
$server = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server 'yourServer';
$db = $server.Databases['yourDB'];
$procs = $db.StoredProcedures | where {$_.Schema -eq 'ABC'};
foreach ( $proc in $procs ) {
   $proc.ChangeSchema('XYZ');
}
```